# Enterprise Edition Code in Examples

Tags: discussion

I have seen, on occasion, a few snippets from EE-only modules slip into answers. I have even very nearly been guilty of it myself.

What is the policy for flagging these other than an edit to remove the offending code? Is there an appropriate or suggest moderator flag?

Comment: I think basically this is for Magento Inc. to decide? Let's ping them?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Mosses has been pinged. Can you post links to posts in question? I've seen on instance but all of the functional bits had been stripped.

Comment: I will look for an example. I saw one yesterday - stay tuned.

Comment: Examples: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3464/email-template-variable-missing-when-overriding-observer-of-core-module/3512#3512 and http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5017/5

Comment: Good question indeed! Thanks for taking up the communication lines, @benmarks. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Per the direction of Mosses Akizian](https://twitter.com/monocat/status/352169670901641216), I have just sent the following email to copyright@ebay.com, with cc to Mosses and to Vinai Kopp:*

> To whom it may concern:
>
> I am a two year veteran of Magento U developer training, working under
>   Vinai Kopp, Beth Gomez, and Susie Sedlacek. I am also a moderator pro
>   tempore of the Magento-specific StackExchange site located at
>   http://magento.stackexchange.com. This site is a community-driven
>   question and answer forum for asking and solving application and
>   development questions regarding Magento.
>
> Recently a question was asked
>   ([Enterprise Edition Code in Examples](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/enterprise-edition-code-in-examples?noredirect=1))
>   in the meta section of the site regarding the inclusion of Enterprise
>   Edition code in the body of questions or answers. While the community
>   has a sense that (unnecessarily) including vast sections of EE code
>   should not be allowed, there is a question as to how much code would
>   be acceptable.
>
> I/we believe it is in the best interest of eBay to allow for the fair
>   and reasonable inclusion of a few relevant lines of restricted-license
>   code on the rare occasion when the need arises. We the community would
>   appreciate some guidance on this issue, and we the moderators will
>   gladly edit posts as appropriate should those posts include an
>   excessive and unnecessary amount of restricted-license code.
>
> Please feel free to reply to me directly or to respond to the question
>   which I have linked in the body of this email
>
> Kind regards, Ben Marks

Comment: Any update on this, Ben?

Comment: No. Haven't heard anything. Pinged Mosses again.

Comment: Per Mosses's request, I've resent this to copyright@magento.com.

Comment: Curious... any word here

Comment: No response. I say GO FOR IT!