# Should we "feed" our Enterprise Support Tickets here?

Tags: discussion

I am thinking about making it some kind of habit - after an Magento Enterprise Support ticket was resolved by eBay staff - to post this in QA format here.

- Question: Problem description
- Answer (not much more than): "We the patch number EE 12345 from support, tested in in our EE 1.13.0.2 and it works" -> Accept answer

Basically I might have asked on stack exchange before, so of course I do not open a new question and just post the answer.

We might not be able to include the patch and code (see [Enterprise Edition Code in Examples](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/enterprise-edition-code-in-examples)) and maybe not cite support staff. But technically I then do not see any problem.

Shall we allow / promote this kind of questions here?

Answer (score 4):

Outside of some agreement-based restriction, I can't see anything wrong with this approach. I like the idea of having public exposure of support requests, including the ability for others to discuss implementing the patches, outcomes, and issues.